# Simperium duplicates existing records

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, simperium

When my iOS app is started for the first time, it initializes a few entities with default data. The same process is completed for every device of the same user when the app is first installed on the device. This leads to a problem with Simperium, because, even if I have a constraint on one of the entity's attributes, it create duplicates. How can avoid that from happening? Is there a way to make Simperium skip objects locally initialized ? Or to prevent it from inserting duplicates?

Would setting the **simperiumKey** of the entity to a custom constant value which is the same for all the devices of the user fix the issue? I mean, would that prevent Simperium from importing the very same entity from different devices that would produce duplicates and sync conflicts ?

Because I tried that option and it looks like the buckets on Simperium Server are ok, but when I dispose the view and I open it again the entities are not there anymore. When I restart the app they are back again... it looks like they desappear to reappear after resetting the app.. very strange.

**UPDATE**
The problem is that I get duplicated entities if I try to insert the same entity from different device. For example. When I setup my app for the first time, I have a function that initializes CURRENCY entities with codes and other things. The same operation would be done from a different device if the user decides to install the app on a new one. In this case, because the new device will initialize again the CURRENCY entities, those info will generate duplicates and conflict errors. I need a way to make Simperium understand that the entities locally inizialized in the devices must not be duplicated. I would remove the inheritance from SPManagedObject in order to stop Simperium from syncing the entities, but in their turn they have relations with other entities and that would definitively create problems with Simperium, because it will try to sync entities which have relations with objects not inheriting from SPManagedObject. Hope you now have a more clear idea.

Comment: Can you please show the code how are you trying to achieve this.

Comment: Which code? Can you please clarify your request? Tx

Comment: What kind of problem are you facing in Simperium in the first place, ideally the first paragraph says there is a problem. You wrote what you tried, but what exactly is the problem.

Comment: I update my question to give you more details. I cannot write too much in a comment

Comment: Yeah, now I got it. Is it possible to fetch the server entities first. So, as soon as the user launches it will create first. Instead fetch from the server, if nothing found then start inserting.

Comment: It looks like inserting a custom simperiumKey when I loccally save the entities would do the trick, but when I signi out I lose part of the data. I mean, data is deleted on exit, it remains on Simperium's server, but it is not replicated back on my device when I log in again. There is something subtle and the documentation should be improved. The solution, at the moment, was to never call signOutAndRemoveLocalData... I don't know if that will cause further problems later on (I mean not calling signOutAndRemoveLocalData on exit)

Comment: You can raise a bug in Simperium. Either they will give the solution or the recommended way to address this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading various posts on this subject I've understood that not signing out (that means: not calling signOutAndRemoveLocalData) and setting custom simperiumKey-s would prevent data duplication. I tested this solution and it apparently looks good. My app needs Simperium to sync data with other devices of the same user, but it mainly works with the local CoreData database. I hope this solution is good for this scenario.